# RuntimeError when using python keyboard library

Tags: python

I wrote some code to help to copy and paste multiple lines in a program that doesn't allow you to copy and paste multiple rows nicely like excel does. I've tried writing this tool in AHK but something about AHK doesn't seem to play nice with the program in question (RSLogix studio 5000, AHK always misses lines when copy and pasting). The keyboard library I'm using seems to be the issue. I get "OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x000D0000" after 2 or 3 copy and pastes. Otherwise, it does what I need it to do wonderfully, but will crash after getting this error. I'm running this in a 32 bit windows 7 VM. running python 3.8.10 and keyboard library v13.5. If you happen to have some idea of how I might be able to fix this, let me know.

```
import pyautogui
import easygui
import keyboard
import pyperclip
setlines="ctrl+1"
multiline_copy="ctrl+2"
multiline_paste="ctrl+3"
copy_list=[]

while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(setlines):
            lines = easygui.enterbox("Enter number of lines to copy")
            
        if keyboard.is_pressed(multiline_copy):
            copy_list.clear()
            for x in range(int(lines)):
                pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') 
                clp=pyperclip.paste()
                pyperclip.copy("")
                copy_list.append(clp)
                pyautogui.press('down') 
            print(copy_list)

        if keyboard.is_pressed(multiline_paste):
            for x in range(int(lines)): 
                pyperclip.copy(copy_list[x])
                pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')  
                pyautogui.press('enter',presses=3,interval=0.05)
```